# Display contents of text file uploaded from device flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, utf-8, readfile

Using the _localFile and readFile functions below I can choose the correct file and read it as bytes however I am unable to convert back to the correct text in the file. When using utf8 decode I get the following error

> Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 10).

The List of int I get from reading the file starts with

```
[80, 75, 3, 4, 20, 0, 8, 8, 8, 0, 135, 117, 116, 81, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 95, 114, 101, 108, 115, 47, 46, 114, 101, 108, 115, 173, 210, 193, 74, 3, 49, 16, 6, 224, 123, 159, 98, 153, 123, 119, 182, 85, 68, 100, 179, 189, 136, 208, 155, 72, 125, 128, 144, 204, 238, 6, 155, 76, 72, 166, 90, 223, 222, 80, 10, 186, 80, 86, 193, 30, 51, 249, 231, 231, 35, 164, 221, 28, 253, 190, 122, 167, 148, 29, 7, 5, 171, 186, 129, 138, 130, 97, 235, 194, 160, 224, 117, 247, 180, 188, 135, 77, 183, 104, 95, 104, 175, 165, 68, 242, 232, 98, 174, 202, 78, 200, 10, 70, 145, 248, 128, 152, 205, 72, 94, 231, 154, 35, 133, 114, 211, 115, 242, 90, 202, 49, 13, 24, 181, 121, 211, 3, 225, 186, 105, 238, 48, 253, 236, 128, 110, 210, 89, 109, 173, 130, 180, 181, 43, 168, 118, 159, 145, 254, 215, 141, 158, 68, 91, 45, 26, 13, 39, 90, 198, 84, 182, 147, 56, 202, 165, 92, 167, 129, 68, 129, 101, 243, 92, 198, 249, 148, 168, 75, 51, 224, 101, 208, 250, 239, 32, 238, 123, 103, 232, 145, 205, 193, 83, 144, 75, 46, 5...
```

and has a length of 24596 where as the text file only has 5601 characters. How do I get the contents of the file I have read in?
Thanks

```
Future<List<int>> readFile() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;
      // Read the file.
      List<int> contents = await file.readAsBytes();
      return contents;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      // If encountering an error, return 0.
      return [0];
    }
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await FlutterDocumentPicker.openDocument();
    return File('$path');
  }
```

Comment: Probably the file is not utf8 encoded. Using the `allowMalformed` param of utf8.decode (see the [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/Utf8Codec/decode.html)), the error is avoided and some characters are replaced? In that case, try to decode the file contents with an online tool, to find out the correct decoder. 
A simple trick to check the encoding of a file in Windows is to open it in Notepad and look at the proposed type in "Save as" (it usually recognize the most common encodings, but isn't a rule).

Comment: Thank you I have found that the file is encoded using ANSI, how do I decode this in dart then?

Answer (score 0):

To convert the `List<int>` data correctly, you need to know how it was encoded. If you do not know, it may be useful to try to open the file with the Windows notepad and see which encoding offers you in the "Save as" window, and/or do some conversion tests with online tools (this is a practical approach, because it is not always possible to understand in retrospect which encoding was used).  Then you can proceed with the decoding:

- for **UTF-8**, you can use the built-in **`dart:convert`** package;
- for **UTF-16** and **UTF-32**, you can use the **`utf`** package (it's discontinued, but I didn't find alternatives);
- for **ANSI**: ANSI characters after 128 change according to the country, so the exact charset ("code page") used must be identified. For example in Western Europe (for latin scripts), this can be Windows-1250 or Windows-1252. The only package I found that supports these encodings is [charset_converter](https://pub.dev/packages/charset_converter) (it supports various charset, but it's available only for Android and iOS, because it relies on the native API of these systems, for example in Android on the API offered by Java).

Example for ANSI (which seems to be your case), for the "windows1250" code page:

(after including `charset_converter` in dependencies and importing it)

```
List<int> contents = await file.readAsBytes();
var decoded = await CharsetConverter.decode("windows1250", Uint8List.fromList(contents));
```

Comment: I have used the charset_converter package with windows1252 code page and can get back to what is displayed in notepad however when the zero is decoded the file decode stops there and I am only able to get back to what is displayed in notepad and not a word processer. Below is what is displayed in notepad,PK\00\00tpQ\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00_rels/.rels\AD\D2\C1J1\E0{\9Fb\99{w\B6UDd\B3\BD\88ЛH}\80\90\CC\EE\9BLH\A6Z\DF\DEP
\BAPV\C13\F9\E7\E7#\A4\DD\FD\BEz\A7\94\AB\BA\81\8A\82a\EB \E0u.

Comment: The notepad file is encoded using Microsoft OOXML

Comment: The file I am trying to read is a docx file

Comment: It is normal that you see it as in Notepad (if you are using the Text widget). It is very different to show a **docx** compared to a pure-text file. The simplest solution would be to find a suitable package; try searching in pub.dev, and in previous Stackoverflow threads specific about docx in flutter. I saw that there is a **flutter_filereader** package that might be right for you, but I've never tried it. But keep in mind that with some packages (like url_launcher) you can open docx files in android / ios but opening them in a new window, not inside your app, so maybe they are not for you.

Comment: Ive been able to open them in other apps using file_reader and open_file however I need the text in the local app

Comment: But have you looked at the package I recommended to you? From [flutter_filereader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_filereader) readme: "A **local** file view widget,Support a variety of file types, such as Doc Eexcl PPT TXT and so on, Android is implemented by Tencent X5,iOS is implemented by WKWebView". This is not to open file in external apps, but **inside** your app (using a not standard native WebView)

Comment: Can you use the flutter_filereader package with a path got from document_picker package as opppossed to a file in your assets?

Comment: This is what i was after, have managed to open the file locally now. Can you save the file content as a string to use locally in the app?

Comment: Any other package you can use to save the file locally and which also allows you to upload to app stores?

Answer (score 0):

To read ANSI encoded files, the `enough_convert` package can read them and it works on all platforms!